# Can I say "X feels close..."?

Tags: grammar, adjectives

Example:

> He feels so close at times, but so distant at others.

(Meaning that the person is open and communicative but also cold and indifferent in occasions.)

Comment: Acceptable as personal figurative speech, yes.

Comment: 'he feels close' to who/what?

Comment: @ Jon Mark Perry close to person who's saying the sentence.

Comment: Who is that then?

Comment: @JonMarkPerry I guess the full sentence would be "He feels so close (to me) at times..."

Comment: what did you think was wrong in the first place?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You’ve used “distant” correctly to metaphorically indicate someone who is cold or withdrawn.

“Close” is a decent opposite already, but some more natural antonyms in this case might be:

- **warm**

  > readily showing affection, gratitude, cordiality, or sympathy
  > <sub>Source: [Definition of “warm” on merriam-webster.com](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/warm)</sub>
- **attentive**

  > 1. Paying close attention; alert or observant: *an attentive listener; attentive to detail.*
  > 2. Showing care for the needs or desires of others; caring or courteous.
  >
  > <sub>Source: [Definition of “attentive” on thefreedictionary.com](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/attentive)</sub>

The word that popped into my mind was “present”, but dictionaries seem to think that this particular use of the word is falling out of fashion.

Answer (score 2):

He feels so close to me at times, but so distant at other times.